# AngularJS add data array to $http request

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs, xmlhttprequest, angularjs-http

I'm going to add some data in an array to `$http` service in angularjs. The way I add them to service is mentioned below (and it works properly)

```
var inputValueArray  = new Array($scope.formdata);
```

I can get data by index **zero in my api.** But I want to get by **named index.** So, I do something like this:

```
var inputValueArray  = new Array();
inputValueArray["myIndex"] = $scope.formData;
```

But, in api I get **empty array**. Then I did this solution:

```
var inputValueArray = {"myIndex" : $scope.formData};
```

Now I get `Maximum call stack size exceeded` error. In both , I use `$_POST` to get data. I mean I'm sending data by **$.param()** like this :

```
data: $.param({ mydata:inputValueArray , csrf_token: myTokenKey})
```

Any idea would highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

According to ECMAScript 2015 (ES6) standard javascript has a Map implementation.

[link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map)

Example:

```
var myMap = new Map();

var keyString = "a string",
    keyObj = {},
    keyFunc = function () {};

// setting the values
myMap.set(keyString, "value associated with 'a string'");
myMap.set(keyObj, "value associated with keyObj");
myMap.set(keyFunc, "value associated with keyFunc");

myMap.size; // 3

// getting the values
myMap.get(keyString);    // "value associated with 'a string'"
myMap.get(keyObj);       // "value associated with keyObj"
myMap.get(keyFunc);      // "value associated with keyFunc"

myMap.get("a string");   // "value associated with 'a string'"
                         // because keyString === 'a string'
myMap.get({});           // undefined, because keyObj !== {}
myMap.get(function() {}) // undefined, because keyFunc !== function () {}
```

Comment: Thank you. But again the same problem.

Comment: please upload your code to JSFiddle or other application, and I will try to help you.

Comment: I get a very stupid error in JSFiddle. I can't instantiate my app. Would you please check this? https://jsfiddle.net/6kstm3e8/25/

Comment: How did you solved that error? your code was similar to mine. Here is all codes : https://jsfiddle.net/6kstm3e8/34/ , But I get this error : `ReferenceError: $ is not defined`